# Cassandra Batch fails across multiple datacenters

Tags: cassandra

We are using Cassandra's Multi Partition LOGGED Batches.
Consistency Level of Writes is LOCAL_QUORUM.

There are two datacenters DC1 and DC2.
For a batch with two Partition keys K1 & K2
Let us say that Partition Key K1 belongs to DC1 & Partition Key K2 belongs to DC2.

Writes don't succeed

Why is this the case?

Comment: When you say "fails", what is the message you receive? When you say different DCs, my guess is that you're processing against different/multiple tables? As you're hitting multiple data centers, there is no "correct" data center to initiate the write to (no difference between one v.s. the other).

Comment: Are they timing out? How many queries in the batch? What's logged on the server? What exception do you get on the client?

Comment: Could not execute batch statement with local quorum